# PHP is it OK to try access an associative array if you are unsure the key exists?

Tags: php

Is it OK to rely on PHP's behaviour if a key is not in the array? Which is:

> Attempting to access an array key which has not been defined is the same as accessing any other undefined variable: an E_NOTICE-level error message will be issued, and the result will be NULL.

For instance if I do not know $_POST contains certain keys is it OK to just try? I want the result to be null anyway. Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you should always develop with error reporting turned on, you want to avoid triggering avoidable errors so as to keep error reporting useful to you. As such, no, it's not okay. Use `isset` or `empty`. For a more in-depth excursion into this topic see [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isset()` to check if it exists and if so do stuff.

```
if(isset($_POST["key"])){// do stuff}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`empty()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) to test it.

Answer (score 0):

If it is necessary to check if a key exists even if it the key is set to null then array_key_exists(mixed $key , array $search) will be usefull.  But it is very slow compared to isset(). So isset() shall be used if you check for a key that is in the array and not null.

Answer (score 0):

`isset()`function can save you from the warning of index not found by checking for it first

`isset($_POST['notSure']) ? $var= $_POST['notSure'] : $var = null;`